# Filter by date hh:mm using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, filter, nspredicate

I have array containing multiple dictionaries in which there is a field that stores hours and minutes like "14:22".

How can I filter array by time? e.g. I want all dictionaried where that field has time > 01:00 and time < 18:00

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do what you're looking for:

```
NSArray *data = @[@{@"time": @"10:05"},@{@"time": @"1:06"},@{@"time": @"18:24"},@{@"time": @"7:29"},@{@"time": @"11:55"}];
NSArray *filteredData = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dict, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSArray *components = [dict[@"time"] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSAssert(components.count >= 2, @"Invalid time format.");
    NSInteger h = [components[0] integerValue];
    NSInteger m = [components[1] integerValue];
    return h >= 1 && h < 18;
}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store the values into an array and use this

```
[datesArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

it will sort u the time

Comment: The question was about *filtering*, not about *sorting*.